# TcpClient don't receive any data with ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, tcpclient

I'm struggling to find out why `TcpClient` don't receive any data in server side if it has called through `ajax`.

However, if I put **breakpoint** in my server side code it works fine even if I have called it with ajax.

I also investigated to find out if my JavaScript function is asynchronous but it seems my JavaScript function is fine.

**JavaScript function**:

```
$('#btnGO').click(function () {

        var url = 'Home/Command';
        var data = { Location: $('#Location').val() };

        $.when($.getJSON(url, data)).then(function (result) {
            $('.Console').html(result);
        });

});
```

**Server side:**

```
TcpClient tc = new TcpClient("Host Address", 23);
return Json(tc.Connected + " " + tc.Available, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Output if I **put** breakpoint in serverside:

> true 22

Output if I don't **put** breakpoint in serverside:

> true 0

Comment: I think you'd want to call `GetStream()`, and then call `Read()` on the returned `NetworkStream`. `Read()` is blocking, and won't allow your action method to return prematurely. Right now, there are no blocking calls to prevent your action method from instantly returning (faster than your tcp client receives data), which is why you get 22 when you put in a break point - it doesn't instantly return. It seems awkward that your UI responsiveness depends on somebody sending data to your API via a socket though....

Comment: Okay, let me emphasize this more: It's really strange what you're doing. Your UI will be waiting for a client to send data to your API via a socket. 

Having said that, check out the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Steve'saD Thank you. Please write your comment as answer, so I can choose it.

Comment: I did. If you tell me what you're actually trying to do - i.e. what app you're trying to make - I may be able to point you in the right direction

Comment: Your first sentence makes me think you just want to send data from javascript, to your api/endpoint. You don't need a socket for that, just put a model in your signature and let mvc/web api do it's model binding....

Comment: @Steve'saD No, I was try to execute some `telnet` commands with `tcpclient`. For the problem in my question `NetworkStream.Read()` solved my problem. However, when I used `NetworkStream.Write()` thread didn't wait for `Write()` to be done. So I had to use Thread.Sleep(1000) after `NetworkStream.Write()`

Comment: oh okay. The docs say that Write is also blocking, so you shouldn't need to sleep the thread.... you should make sure you're doing it right: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.write(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Steve'saD I do believe that `Write` blocks until it writes to buffer. I don't think it waits until end point receives message and send response. That is why if I immediately call `Read` after `Write` I receive nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd want to call GetStream(), and then call Read() on the returned NetworkStream. Read() is blocking, and won't allow your action method to return prematurely. Right now, there are no blocking calls to prevent your action method from instantly returning (faster than your tcp client receives data), which is why you get 22 when you put in a break point - it doesn't instantly return. It seems awkward that your UI responsiveness depends on somebody sending data to your API via a socket though....

let me emphasize this more: It's really strange what you're doing. Your UI will be waiting for a client to send data to your API via a socket. Having said that, check out the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream(v=vs.110).aspx